# Word or phrase for a gentle or kind act by a gruff person?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

After my wife gave our postman an end-of-year tip, he bought our young girls some donuts as a treat. It was a kind, gentle gesture and he seemed *almost* a little uncomfortable doing it — he's sort of a gruff, manly-man type of person.

Anyway, we were wondering if there's a good word or phrase that describes this *kind* of thing (excuse the pun): a gentle act done by a normally gruff person (or relatedly, maybe a person who seems gruff but really isn't).

Comment: There are many ways to describe the behavior but as for a single word, it would help if you would provide a sample sentence with a blank where you imagine that word should be.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking of something parallel to "that was a gentlemanly gesture" (but *gentlemanly* isn't the right word here as it doesn't capture the "gruff" part).

Comment: Fun question. I can think of adjectives for such a person, like "big softie" or describing such a man as a "teddy-bear". No adverbs come to mind though. Often I see writers describe the character, making him gruff and manly, then use a word like "gently," "tenderly," or "carefully" for the contrast.

Comment: You could say that it was *out of character*.

Comment: Teeing off of  @BladorthinTheGrey's suggestion, you might say that his gesture was uncharacteristically (kind, thoughtful, etc.)

Comment: @KristinaLopez Is using "unusually" too strong? Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @Rathony, I don't think "unusually" is too strong.  I don't think I have a tight enough answer in mind yet. :-)

Comment: With @Kristina Lopez's thinking you could use "roughly" as an adjective, because it sort of implies the gruffness but in the context of your question it may work?

Comment: I think @KristinaLopez 's "uncharacteristically kind" (by way of Bladortin's "out of character") describes such conflicting events perfectly, but if you were thanking the postman himself (in a TY note, for example), I'd consider using "exceptionally kind," which would give him the option to interpret "exceptionally" as "1-forming an exception or rare instance; unusual; extraordinary" (="uncharacteristically," imo) or "2-.unusually excellent; superior."

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Couldn't that be taken as kind of offensive, since you would also be saying he doesn't seem like a person who would do nice things?

Answer (score 2):

Not a word, but a longish phrase.

> Don't let her/his rough exterior fool you; underneath that grumpy disposition **[beats a heart of gold](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heart_of_gold)**
> <sub>Wiktionary</sub>

TV tropes has a page dedicated to **Jerk with a Heart of Gold**, which is a much shorter phrase.

> A person you would expect to be a big Jerkass has some redeeming qualities behind their tough demeanor. Occasionally, they'll try to make it a [Hidden Heart of Gold](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HiddenHeartOfGold).

And for the latter, TV Tropes describes the character thus

> **Hidden Heart of Gold**
>
> Bob is a total Jerkass. He's the type to knock a guy down and kick him when he tries to get up, the type who'll bed a girl then toss her aside. Just ask anyone. […] So why is a nice girl like Alice with him? Well Alice knows of a different side, one where he's always nice to her when they're together; **she's seen him do a few good deeds when he didn't know she was watching.** Like reading to orphans, making donations to charity, or just plain helping others. Thing is, eventually Alice is going to confront him about his true self, call him out for his crime of... kindness.